# How can I create a proc univariate on a sum of two variables?

Tags: sas

I get error messages when I try to create the variable distribution. These two variables exists in the data but I am trying to find the distribution for the sum of it.

```
proc univariate data=data.performance;
var sum(inc_Cash, out_wire);
quit;
```

Answer (score 5):

The variables need to be summed prior to the proc univariate step.
This can be done in a data step, or a view is another option.

- Data step option

```
data performance;
set data.performance;
total = sum(inc_cash, out_wire);
run;


proc univariate data=performance;
var total;
run;
```

- View option

```
data perf / view=perf;
set data.performance;
total = sum(inc_cash, out_wire);
run;


proc univariate data=perf;
var total;
run;
```